# HRESULT Enumeration C#

Tags: c#, winapi

Does anybody know where i can find HRESULT enumeration for C#? I tryed to find this for a 2 days.

Comment: From .NET, you can use static method `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR` to map a (negative) _signed_ 32-bit integer HRESULT into an object containing a message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HRESULT` is not suitable for an enumeration. It is a 32 bit integer value for which different ranges of bits carry different meaning.

Comment: This being said, it is very often useful to define an enum with the values of HRESULT that you expect to see in your application.

Comment: WinError.h enumerates a lot of them with NAMES like E_FAIL

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that such an enumeration exists : when a COM exception is raised, the CLR tries to transform it into a .NET standard exception. If it's not possible, you will just receive a generic exception. This is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1.aspx).

Comment: maybe some parsers for HRESULT exists?

Comment: What do you mean by a parser?

Comment: Different COM objects can use the same HRESULT for different meanings. So a given HRESULT cannot be translated unambiguously to an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package [nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0) and use the class `VSConstants`.

Comment: And don't think you can get it with version `nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0`

Answer (score 0):

I use **StreamSocket** for communication where a **COMException** exception may occur.
I use the **SocketErrorStatus** enumerator for this exception.
Sample code:

```
try
{ 
    // ...
}
catch (COMException comEx)
{
    SocketErrorStatus socketErrorStatus = SocketError.GetStatus(comEx.HResult);
    switch (socketErrorStatus)
    {
        case SocketErrorStatus.Unknown: break;
        case SocketErrorStatus.OperationAborted: break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

A special source of exception has a special enumerator.
There is no universal enumerator.

Source:

```
Assembly: Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract 
namespace Windows.Networking.Sockets 
public enum SocketErrorStatus 
public static class SocketError
```